# XBAP, Fulltrust application security / trust exception

Tags: security, xbap, full-trust

There are alot of settings in all the versions of IE & windows, that may cause problems for users attempting to run xbap applications, particulary in fulltrust mode.

I seem to have gathered a long list of such cases during the last year.
However I'm pussled by this one exception, which occurs on a user on one of my systems, and was hoping that maybe someone here could point me in the right direction.

This application runs on all the used version of windows, and IE6 -> IE9, without problems so there is nothing wrong with the deployment/xbap it self. 
The user gets the errorlog / stacktrace below. Have anyone of you encountered this vague trace, and know what the issue might be? This user is running IE8 & W7.

The user have the proper certificates installed in trusted root authorities & trusted publishers. The site in question has been added to list of trusted sites. Xbap has been enabled in IE.

URLs, publickeys, appname etc have been scrambeled.

Brgds,
Stian

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
      Windows                 : 6.1.7600.0 (Win32NT)
      Common Language Runtime       : 2.0.50727.4963
      System.Deployment.dll         : 2.0.50727.4927 (NetFXspW7.050727-4900)
      mscorwks.dll                  : 2.0.50727.4963 (win7RTMGDR.050727-4900)
      dfshim.dll              : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
      Deployment url                : http://someurl/someapplication.xbap
      Application url               : http://someurl/Application%20Files/someapplication_1_0_0_29/someapplication.exe.manifest

IDENTITIES
      Deployment Identity           : someapplication.app, Version=1.0.0.29, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=sometoken, processorArchitecture=msil
      Application Identity          : someapplication, Version=1.0.0.29, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=sometoken, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
      * Online only application.
      * Browser-hosted application.

ERROR SUMMARY
      Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
      * An exception occurred while determining trust. Following failure messages were detected:
            + User has refused to grant required permissions to the application.
      * An exception occurred while downloading the application. Following failure messages were detected:
            + The AssertApplicationRequirements method failed. The application cannot be committed.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
      No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
      There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
      No phase information is available.

ERROR DETAILS
      Following errors were detected during this operation.
      * [01/11/2011 09:16:02] System.Deployment.Application.TrustNotGrantedException (Unknown subtype)
            - User has refused to grant required permissions to the application.
            - Source: System.Deployment
            - Stack trace:
                  at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationTrust.RequestTrust(SubscriptionState subState, Boolean isShellVisible, Boolean isUpdate, ActivationContext actCtx, TrustManagerContext tmc)
                  at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.DetermineTrustCore(Boolean blocking, TrustParams tp)
                  at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.DetermineTrust(TrustParams trustParams)
                  at System.Deployment.Application.InPlaceHostingManager.AssertApplicationRequirements(Boolean grantApplicationTrust)
                  at System.Deployment.Application.InPlaceHostingManager.AssertApplicationRequirements()
                  at MS.Internal.AppModel.XappLauncherApp.AssertApplicationRequirementsAsync(Object unused)
      * [01/11/2011 09:16:37] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (Unknown subtype)
            - The AssertApplicationRequirements method failed. The application cannot be committed.
            - Source: System.Deployment
            - Stack trace:
                  at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.WaitForAssertApplicationRequirements()
                  at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeCore(Boolean blocking)
                  at System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentManager.SynchronizeAsyncWorker()

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
      No transaction information is available.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have answered this one when I "solved" the issue.

In the case above there was an issue with the client computer, a change of disk, re-install of OS etc solved the trick.

What the issue was, remains a mystery ;)